# GeoServer caching request not aligned to grid(s)

Tags: geoserver, javascript, tiles, geowebcache

For starters, just to point out I have really gone through all posts here on this issue and none of the solutions are working for me.

I have a lot of GeoServer layers which I am serving in `EPSG:3765` without a problem to my app. However, when I turn on caching using GeoServer integrated GWC, the trouble begins. I created a new gridset as in the image:

[image: GeoServer Gridset settings]

The pixel sizes I calculated by dividing the coordinate difference (e.g. `X2-X1` or `Y2-Y1`, the result is the same) of tile bounds(from the http request params) at respective zoom levels with 256 and calculated the result on `pow(-1)`. Maybe this is where I went wrong but adding normal zoom levels without any change hasn't done it for me either.
All my layer extents are set to SRID extent, my request is set to tile width and height 256. I think I am doing something wrong with defining pixel size /scale but for the life of me, I can't get it right. I also tried changing CRS extent to the one defined on SRS official page, hasn't made any difference. My projection and view are defined like this:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:3765', "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

var htrs = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3765');

var view = new ol.View({center: [467500, 5101500],
projection: htrs,
minZoom: 7,
maxZoom: 20,
zoom: 12 });
```

All of my layers, have a 'TILED':true parameter. The error I am getting is

```
geowebcache-cache-result "MISS"  
geowebcache-miss-reason "request does not align to grid(s) 'grid_3765'"
```

I am a newbie at Geoserver, GWC and JavaScript and have no idea anymore what I could be doing wrong. Any solutions?

Comment: you need to add the code that creates your resolution array and tiled layer to the question - see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html for a working example

Comment: I did what you proposed, and got an error which said my projection had no recognized extent, so I set it accordingly to Geoserver extent bounds for EPSG:3765, which is different from the extent on http://spatialreference.org. Now my layer is miss aligned on zoom levels 0-5 with the occasional "column out of range" exception error. Caching seems okay for other zoom levels. I tried other combinations with the spatialreference.org bounds definition, emptying the cache on Geoserver and restarting caching, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution. My projection extent was wrong, which I realised by looking into the GWC GET request info in my web browser. I saw my extent was different from the one assigned to the tile for zoom level 0(0, 0, 0), read the new coordinates and assigned them to my projection extent and custom gridset. Now it works like a charm. By what I've read on some forums, it seems GeoWebCache and GeoServer have different extent value for some projections. I'm sorry my browsers language is Croatian, but you get the idea. Hope this helps someone.

[image: GWC Get Request]